# Keep custom fields during supervoxel clustering process in Point Cloud Library (PCL)

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am new at PCL (Point Cloud Library), and I was trying to implement supervoxel_clustering ([this link](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/supervoxel_clustering.php)) on my custom dataset. My point clouds dataset has these fields: `X Y Z R G 
B L1 L2` where  R, G, B are `integer` values between `0-255` and L1 and L2 are 
`integer` labels.

After applying supervoxel, I save the point clouds with their labels:

```
/// save the labeled cloud 
PointLCloudT::Ptr labeled_cloud = super.getLabeledCloud(); 
pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII("/path/labeled_cloud.pcd", *labeled_cloud);
```

My question is: how to transfer my labels and colors from original point 
clouds during the process. I try to define my own point type, something like: `X Y Z R G B L1 L2 L3`, but with the 
tutorial on point types it is not trivial to do that. 
One dummy solution I am thinking of, is using KD-tree and transfer labels from 
supervoxel result to the original points, but still I need to read my 
original points with all custom fields in pcl.

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks, 
Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you have already defined a point type with L1 and L2 fields.

The points come out from supervoxel_clustering in the same order as they were put in and the getLabeledCloud() method returns all the original points. The easiest solution is to define the point cloud with L1, L2 and L3 fields and copy your original point cloud to that type and then iterate over the cloud and copy the label from labeled_cloud.

something like

```
pcl::PointCloud<your_custom_point_type_with_L1_L2_L3> combined_cloud;
pcl::copyPointCloud( original_cloud, combined_cloud );

for ( int i = 0; i < labeled_cloud->point.size(); i++ ){
    combined_cloud[i].label3 = labeled_cloud[i].label;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking of this solution, it is easy but not safe. Because if during supervoxle process one of the original points will be removed, or there would be NaN values, or for any other reason the order changes then just copying labels will make a mess.

Comment: But does it filter out nan values? I think it doesn't. If you look at the milk_cartoon_all_small_clorox.pcd point cloud in your example it seems to have nan (xyz are nan, color value exists) points and yet the getLabeledCloud() method return exactly the same amount of points and the ones that do have xyz data are the matches.

Comment: Add 

std::cout << cloud->points[0] << "\n" << cloud->points[1] << "\n";

in the example code and it'll print out 
(nan,nan,nan - 18,23,9,0)
(nan,nan,nan - 18,21,11,0)

Does your implementation remove points?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried to read my custom format and feed it into supervoxel function, but some functions just export  PCL standard types. So I should follow your advice. One more questions: do you know how I can write rgb values as float in ascii pcd. I use pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII to save the custom datatype as ascii pcd with their rgb, but I am afraid I am loosing the original color during packing/unpacking. I am using http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/structpcl_1_1_r_g_b.html
 to convert rgb from int to float.

Comment: Something like this? Bitshifting the integer values to PCL rgb value?uint8_t red = 20;
        uint8_t green = 100;
        uint8_t blue = 55;
        uint32_t rgb = ((uint32_t)blue)<<16 | ((uint32_t)green)<<8 | ((uint32_t)red);
        p.rgba = rgb;